# Pillarboxing AVC/h.264 video with minimal re-encoding?

Tags: encoding, software-recommendation, h.264, aspect, bluray

I have 1440x1080 AVC/h.264 video that should be displayed with a 4:3 aspect ratio (which would correspond to square pixels).  I'd like to burn it to a Blu-ray disc to be playable in Blu-ray players, but my understanding is that [Blu-ray specifies that 1440x1080 video should be treated as 16:9](https://www.videohelp.com/hd) (which makes no sense to me, but I digress).

Are there any software tools (whether for Windows, Linux, or macOS) that can pillarbox AVC/h.264 video **without lossily re-encoding the existing content**?  That is, it seems conceivable that 15 columns of 16x16 macroblocks could be added to each of the left and right sides to make it 1920x1080 without going through a lossy decode/encode cycle.

Comment: I've found https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4331 which requested such a feature for ffmpeg, but it sadly was closed as won't-fix without comment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using ffmpeg to add height (as black bars) to video file without quality loss](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/24755/using-ffmpeg-to-add-height-as-black-bars-to-video-file-without-quality-loss)

Comment: @tabdiukov Thanks!  That's definitely a very similar question, although the answers there don't help (they do a full re-encode), and I'm not asking specifically about ffmpeg.